# detecting and counting gaps VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question regarding finding and detecting gaps per row in VBA excel.
The dificult part is gaps that start on Friday and run until Thursday (FTGaps) need to be added up seperately and gaps starting on other days have to be counted seperately.

So for instance in the picture the result from the first row has to be: 1 FTGap and 1 Gap
And the second row has to be 1 FTGap.

[image]

But if there is a empty cell earlier in the row it has to be counted as a different gap.
So for instance the following rows output is 2 gaps and 1 FTGap.

[image]

I hope my question is clear.
Thanks in advance

What I tried

```
For Row = 3 To Worksheets("Kalender2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
GapDays = 0
FTGapDays = 0

For col = 2 To 55 'Worksheets("Kalender2").Cells(2, 
Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If Worksheets("Kalender2").Cells(Row, col) = "0" And 
    Worksheets("Kalender2").Cells(2, col).Value = "Friday" Then
        
            FTGapDays = FTGapDays + 1
            
        ElseIf Worksheets("Kalender2").Cells(Row, col) = "0" And 
   FTGapDays <> 0 Then
            FTGapDays = FTGapDays + 1  'doortellen gap startend op 
  vrijdag
            
        ElseIf Worksheets("Kalender2").Cells(Row, col) = "0" And 
 FTGapDays = 0 Then 'And Worksheets("Kalender2").Cells(2, Col).Value <> 
"Friday"  Then
            GapDays = GapDays + 1   'eerste lege cel andere dag dan 
 vrijdag
           
    End If
Next col

If col = 54 Then
    Call EndGap
End If
```

Call EndGap
Next Row
'

And then the second Sub Endgap():

```
If FTGapDays <> 0 Then
If FTGapDays < 7 Then
    If GapDays = 0 Then
        Gaps = Gaps + 1
    End If
ElseIf FTGapDays >= 7 And FTGapDays < 14 Then
    FTGaps = FTGaps + 1
    If GapDays = 0 Then
        Gaps = Gaps + 1
    End If
ElseIf FTGapDays >= 14 And FTGapDays < 21 Then
    FTGaps = FTGaps + 2
    If GapDays = 0 Then
        Gaps = Gaps + 1
    End If
ElseIf FTGapDays >= 21 And FTGapDays < 28 Then
    FTGaps = FTGaps + 3
    LegGaps = LegGaps + 1
    If GapDays = 0 Then
        Gaps = Gaps + 1
    End If
ElseIf FTGapDays >= 28 And FTGapDays < 35 Then
    FTGaps = FTGaps + 4
    LegGaps = LegGaps + 1
    If GapDays = 0 Then
        Gaps = Gaps + 1
    End If
ElseIf FTGapDays >= 35 And FTGapDay < 42 Then
    FTGaps = FTGaps + 5
    LegGaps = LegGaps + 1
    If GapDays = 0 Then
        Gaps = Gaps + 1
    End If
ElseIf FTGapDays = 42 Then
    FTGaps = FTGaps + 6
    LegGaps = LegGaps + 2
End If
```

End If

End Sub

Comment: I tried alot, which i dont think is usefull for the question because It didnt worked. I first collected al the empty cells and then a loop if column is Friday then FTGaps = FTGaps + 1.   If i had an empty cell earlier in the row it did not counted that cell as a gap seperately.

Comment: You must prove that tried something by your own. Plese, edit your question and show us what you tried, even if it does not work as you need. Then, how would you like the result of processing to be returned?

Comment: I've added my code

Comment: Since you use `If Worksheets("Kalender2").Cells(Row, col) = "0"`, should we understand that what we see are not `0` (value)? Is there a zero text? Then, the row containing the days name looks to be the second none. Is this deduction correct? We cannot see it in the pictures yo show us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

---

We have a range (apparently `"B3:BC" & UsedRange.Rows.count`). The range is preceded by a row (`B2:BC2`) containing days of the week repeated in consecutively order: Monday, Tuesday, etc.

Cells for each row in the range contain either a `0` or some other value (integer? does not matter much). Consecutive `0`'s in a row (length > 0) are treated as a *gap*. We have two types of gaps:

- a regular `Gap`: a range of consecutive `0`'s of any length > 0;
- a Friday-through-to-Thursday-Gap (`FtGap`): a range of consecutive `0`'s, that starts on a *Friday* and ends on Thursday (length = 7).

For each row we want to count the number of `Gaps` and `FtGaps`, taking into account the following condition: a range of consecutive `0`'s that qualifies as a `FtGap` should *not* also be counted as a regular `Gap`.

#### Solution

---

To solve this problem, I've used range `B3:BC20` for the data. Cells in this range have been populated randomly with either `0`'s or `1`'s (but this value could be anything) using `=IF(RAND()>0.8,0,1)`. My row with "days of the week" starts with a "Monday", but this should make no difference.

I've used the following method:

1. Create two arrays for row days and the data.
2. Loop through each row array with nested loop through cols to access all cells per row.
3. On each new `0`, increment the total `Gap` count (`GapTrack`) by 1. For each new `0`, increment a variable (`GapTemp`) by 1 that tracks the length of the `Gap`. Reset `GapTemp` on the next non-`0`.
4. For each `0` on a "Friday", start incrementing a variable `FtTemp`. We keep checking if its value (length) has reached any multiple of 7. When it does, we increment the `Ft` count (`FtTrack`) by 1.
5. On each new non-`0`, check if `FtTemp mod 7 = 0` and `GapTemp Mod 7 = 0 and GapTemp > 0`. If True, we will have added a regular Gap to our total count of the same length as one or more `FtTemps`. This violates the condition mentioned above. Remedy this by decrementing `GapTrack` by 1.
6. At the end of the row, we wrap `GapTrack` and `FtTrack` inside an array, assign it to a new key in a dictionary. At the start of the next row, we reset all our variables, and restart the count.
7. When the loop is finished, we end up with a dictionary that contains all our counts per row. We write this data away somewhere.

Code as follows with some further notes on what is happening. N.B. I've used "Option Explicit" to force proper declaration of all our variables.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CountGaps()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Kalender2")

Dim rngDays As Range, rngData As Range
Dim arrDays As Variant, arrData() As Variant

Set rngDays = ws.Range("Days") 'Named range referencing $B$2:$BC$2 in "Kalender2!"
Set rngData = ws.Range("Data") 'Named range referencing $B$3:$BC$20 in "Kalender2!"

'populate arrays with range values
arrDays = rngDays.Value 'dimensions:    arrDays(1, 1) to arrDays(1, rngDays.Columns.Count)
arrData = rngData.Value 'dimensions:    arrData(1, 1) to arrData(rngData.rows.Count, rngData.Columns.Count)

'declare ints for loop through rows (i) and cols (i) of arrData
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

'declare booleans to track if we are inside a Gap / FtGap
Dim GapFlag As Boolean, FtFlag As Boolean

'declare ints to track current Gap count (GapTemp), sum Gap count (GapTrack), and same for Ft
Dim GapTemp As Integer, GapTrack As Integer, FtTemp As Integer, FtTrack As Integer

'declare dictionary to store GapTrack and FtTrack for each row
'N.B. in VBA editor (Alt + F11) go to Tools -> References, add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" for this to work
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

'declare int (counter) for iteration over range to fill with results
Dim counter As Integer
'declare key for loop through dict
Dim key As Variant

'-----

'start procedure: looping through arrData rows: (arrData(i,1))
For i = LBound(arrData, 1) To UBound(arrData, 1)
    
    'for each new row, reset variables to 0/False
    GapTemp = 0
    GapTrack = 0
    GapFlag = False
    
    FtTemp = 0
    FtTrack = 0
    FtFlag = False
    
    'nested loop through arrData columns: (arrData(i,2))
    For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
        
        If arrData(i, j) = 0 Then
            'cell contains 0: do stuff
            
            If arrDays(1, j) = "Friday" Then
                'Day = "Friday", start checking length Ft gap
                FtFlag = True
            End If
            
            'increment Gap count
            GapTemp = GapTemp + 1

            If GapFlag = False Then
            'False: Gap was not yet added to Total Gap count;
            'do this now
                GapTrack = GapTrack + 1
                
                'toggle Flag to ensure continuance of 0 range will not be processed anew
                GapFlag = True
                
            End If
            
            If FtFlag Then
                'We are inside a 0 range that had a Friday in the preceding cells
                'increment Ft count
                FtTemp = FtTemp + 1
                
                If FtTemp Mod 7 = 0 Then
                    'if True, we will have found a new Ft Gap, add to Total Ft count
                    FtTrack = FtTrack + 1
                    
                    'toggle Flag to reset search for new Ft Gap
                    FtFlag = False
                End If
                
            End If
            
        Else
            'cell contains 1: evaluate variables

            If (FtTemp Mod 7 = 0 And GapTemp Mod 7 = 0) And GapTemp > 0 Then
                'if True, then it turns out that our last range STARTED with a "Friday" and continued through to a "Thursday"
                'if so, we only want to add this gap to the Total Ft count, NOT to the Total Gap count
                'N.B. since, in fact, we will already have added this range to the Total Gap count, we need to retract that step
                'Hence: we decrement Total Gap count
                GapTrack = GapTrack - 1
            End If
        
            'since cell contains 1, we need to reset our variables again (except of course the totals)
            GapTemp = 0
            GapFlag = False
            
            FtTemp = 0
            FtFlag = False

        End If
        
    Next j

    'finally, at the end of each row, we assign the Total Gap / Ft counts as an array to a new key (i = row) in our dictionary
    dict.Add i, Array(GapTrack, FtTrack)

Next i

'we have all our data now stored in the dictionary
'example of how we might write this data away in a range:

rngDays.Columns(rngData.Columns.Count).Offset(0, 1) = "Gaps"    'first col to the right of data
rngDays.Columns(rngData.Columns.Count).Offset(0, 2) = "FtGaps"  'second col to the right of data

'set counter for loop through keys
counter = 0
For Each key In dict.Keys
    
    'resize each cell in first col to right of data to fit "Array(GapTrack, FtTrack)" and assign that array to its value ("dict(key)")
    rngData.Columns(rngData.Columns.Count).Offset(counter, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = dict(key)
    'increment counter for next cell
    counter = counter + 1
    
Next key

End Sub
```

Snippet of result:

[image]

Let me know if you experience any difficulties with implemention.

Answer (score 2):

Please, test the next solution. It uses a kind of trick: Dividing a number to 0 in a formula will return an error. So, such a formula is placed two rows down after the last, then using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)` creates a discontinuous range of the gaps and process it. The processing result is returned two columns to the right of the last column. In the first such a column the 'Gaps' and in the second one 'FTGap'. The code assumes that the row keeping the days name is the second and the zero (`0`) seen in your pictures are values not string as you tried using in your code:

```
Sub extractGaps()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long, rng As Range, arrCount, arrRows, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  If sh.Range("A" & lastR).HasFormula Then
    If left(sh.Range("A" & lastR).Formula, 3) = "=1/" Then
        sh.rows(lastR).EntireRow.ClearContents
        lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    End If
  End If
  lastCol = sh.cells(2, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
  ReDim arrCount(1 To lastR - 2, 1 To lastCol)
  
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For i = 3 To lastR
        arrRows = countGaps(sh.Range("A" & i, sh.cells(i, lastCol)), lastR, lastCol)
        arrCount(i - 2, 1) = arrRows(0): arrCount(i - 2, 2) = arrRows(1)
  Next i
  sh.Range("A" & lastR + 2).EntireRow.ClearContents
  sh.cells(3, lastCol + 2).Resize(UBound(arrCount), 2).value = arrCount
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Function countGaps(rngR As Range, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long) As Variant
     Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = rngR.Parent
     Dim rngProc As Range, i As Long, A As Range, FTGap As Long, Gap As Long
     Dim boolGap As Boolean, bigGaps As Double, mtchFr
     
     Set rngProc = sh.Range(sh.cells(lastR + 2, 1), sh.cells(lastR + 2, lastCol)) 'a range where to place a formula returnig errors deviding by 0...
     
      rngProc.Formula = "=1/" & rngR.Address
     On Error Resume Next
      Set rngProc = rngProc.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
     On Error GoTo 0
     If rngProc.cells.count = rngR.cells.count Then
            If IsNumeric(rngProc.cells(1)) Then countGaps = Array(0, 0): Exit Function
     End If
     If rngProc Is Nothing Then countGaps = Array(0, 0): Exit Function 'in case of no gaps...
     
     Gap = 0: FTGap = 0: Debug.Print rngProc.Areas.count
     For Each A In rngProc.Areas
        Debug.Print sh.Range(sh.cells(2, A.cells(1).column), sh.cells(2, A.cells(A.Columns.count).column)).Address: 'Stop
        If A.cells.count < 7 Then
            Gap = Gap + 1
        ElseIf A.cells.count = 7 Then
            If sh.cells(2, A.cells(1).column).value = "Friday" Then
                FTGap = FTGap + 1
            Else
                Gap = Gap + 1
            End If
        Else 'for more than 7 empty cells:
            'set the Friday day position in the empty cells range/area:
            mtchFr = Application.match("Friday", sh.Range(sh.cells(2, A.cells(1).column), sh.cells(2, A.cells(A.Columns.count).column)), 0)
            If A.Columns.count - mtchFr < 6 Then 'no any FTGap existing:
                Gap = Gap + 1
            ElseIf A.cells.count - mtchFr = 6 Then 'fix a FTGap
                Gap = Gap + 1: FTGap = FTGap + 1
            Else
                bigGaps = ((A.cells.count - mtchFr) - i + 1) / 7
                FTGap = FTGap + Int(bigGaps)
                If mtchFr <> 1 Then Gap = Gap + 1 'the gap before Friday
                If A.cells.count - i + 1 - Int(bigGaps) * 7 > 0 Then Gap = Gap + 1
            End If
        End If
     Next A
     countGaps = Array(Gap, FTGap)
End Function
```

Comment: I like this concept, though it is slightly slow (>2x mine). As is, I think it produces erroneous results. Inside `ElseIf A.Cells.Count = 7 Then` delete 2x `: Exit For`. In the next `Else` many gaps are counted 2x. E.g. `A.cells.count = 14` with `A.cells(1) = "Friday"` should = 0 Gaps & 2 FtGaps; your code produces 1 & 3. FtGap goes wrong on `Int(bigGaps)` with more than 1 "Friday": exit after the first match. `If boolGap Then Gap = Gap + 1: etc.` together with `If A.Cells.Count - i + 1 ... Gap + 1: Exit For` is causing doubles for Gap. E.g. when there is a "Friday", but no FtGap.

Comment: One remedy. Delete everything inside `If ... = "Friday" Then` block, and replace with the following: `bigGaps = (A.Cells.Count - i + 1) / 7` \n `FTGap = FTGap + Int(bigGaps)` \n `bigGapsAll = (A.Cells.Count) / 7` \n `If Not bigGapsAll = Int(bigGaps) Then` \n `Gap = Gap + 1` \n
`End If` \n `Exit For`. Together with deleting the aforementioned `Exit For` parts inside `ElseIf A.Cells.Count = 7 Then`, this will now produce the same result as my code above. At least, for my sample it does. And let's hope that result is in fact the result asked for ;).

Comment: @ouroboros1 I've just played with VBA... I had another version and forgot `Exit For` in the case of areas with 7 cells. Not sure I correctly understand your suggestion. Checking the "Friday" day name gives the possibility to also count the gaps before "Friday". Using `bigGaps` variable offers the possibility to determine if there also are empty cells after "Thursday" and count them as `Gap`. No availability now for testing. I am just looking to the code I posted...

Comment: Right. Reading your comment, it dawns on me that we have different conceptions of the desired result for the areas with count > 7. Take count = 10, with "Friday" at 3. IIUC, you say: that will be 2 Gaps (1:2, 10) and 1 FtGap (3:9). This indeed, is what your code is doing. I didn't think of it like that. I assumed: that's 1 Gap (1:10) and (*inside*) there is also 1 FtGap (3:9).  On second thought, your understanding makes a lot more sense. Let's see if the OP can confirm.

Comment: @ouroboros1 In fact, this is which looked to me suitable, according to what I could read. Like you say, let us see what the OP considers is more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you both so much! I ended up using @FaneDuru s solution. I have one question, in case of no gaps (no zeros in the whole row) the formula returns 7 - 28 (7 gaps and 28 FTGaps). Do you know why this is?

Comment: Possibly related to this line: `lastCol = sh.cells(2, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column`, if you kept it, and have other values to the right of your data, in row 2. Check with `Debug.Print sh.Cells(2, lastCol).Address()` if the address makes sense as a reference to your last column. Unrelated to this: can you clarify the correct interpretation of the desired output for longer ranges with zeroes discussed above (couple of comments higher) between @FaneDuru and me. Thanks

Comment: @EvA Ups... I thought that `rngProc` will be `Nothing` and `If rngProc Is Nothing Then countGaps = Array(0, 0): Exit Function` will return an array containing two `0`. Le me check what's happening. I didn't even test such a situation, being convinced that the range in discussion will not be created. And about `@ouroboros1` comment, he meant that for the case of gaps in the interval, let us say, Thursday to Saturday, my code returns one `FtGaps` and two `Gaps`. One before `Fiday` and another after Thursday. His version returns one and one. Both versions can be easily adapted. Mine being simpler

Comment: @EvA Like I supposed,  `rngProc` is **not** `Nothing` as all `SpecialCells` ranges should be if  no any such special cells exist. It returns the whole range. I adapted the above code to check it in a different way and now it returns 0, 0. Please, check it and send some feedback. Also, please try clarifying the dispute about the gaps interpretation...

Comment: @EvA I also checked the code (now) for the case of only gaps and it returns correctly. But based on the same mechanism: One gap before the first Friday and the second one after Thursday... Please, remember to clarify the gaps calculation way/algorithm, from the above mentioned point of view...

Comment: @EvA The code may be optimized to also catch the formula row in a scenario like the next: If the code stops because an error, the rows containing formulas will remain there and being processed by the code. When `lastR` is calculated, using the returned value, the "A1" cell on that last row must be check using `HasFormula`. If it returns true, the row in discussion should be cleared and `lastR` be calculated again. I would dare to say this is a theme for you...:) If problematic, even if I do not think so, I will show you how to proceed...

Comment: Thanks! The output in case of no gaps is now correctly! About the gaps: In the case of count = 10 and Friday on 3, The desired output is then : 1gap and 1FTGap

Comment: @EvA What about 11 empty cells and Friday on the third position?

Comment: 11cells and Friday on the 3rd position  would be 2 gaps and 1 FTGap. (1 Gap: Wed-Thursday, 1FTGap, 1Gap: Friday-Saturday)

Comment: @EvA OK. This is what my code does. When I will be near my laptop I will try adapting it to avoid the second iteration which identifies the Friday day name...

Comment: @EvA OK Please, test the updated code. Like I said before, it does not contain the second loop searching for the firs Friday day name. Now, the code uses `Application.Match` to find this first Friday name...

Comment: Okay thankyou! I will try this when I get home. I didnt really understand what you meant with the optimization of the code in a couple comments above. Also, ive sent you an email dont know if you got it. Ill let you know when I tried the updated version of the code

Comment: @EvA If I so not expect a mail, it is configured to place in Junk folder all mails received from somebody not bein in my address book. I will check it now. Now the code does not iterate through all area cells until if finds the Friday day, for area bigger than 7 cells, which is a reference to count Gaps before and after FTGap... I used 'Application.Match`.